# why creating view from a left join view is not fast?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I created views on the tables
each of them had about 46299 rows 
I created them successfully in phpMyadmin
after that I created a join of these two views 
which itself is a view.
in mysql in a millisecond I got `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)`
but I couldn't reach my phpMyAdmin
so I decided to **drop** the view
in mysql it took about 20 minuets for dropping
again I tried my way and now I can't reach phpMyadmin 
I don't know that it is under prcessing or not?!
how much I should wait? and why mysql show me fast query ok but phpmyAdmin is still processing if It is really under process

```
+-----+------+-----------------+-------+---------+------+--------------+--------
------------------------------------+
| Id  | User | Host            | db    | Command | Time | State        | Info
                                    |
+-----+------+-----------------+-------+---------+------+--------------+--------
------------------------------------+
|   7 | root | localhost:38993 | week1 | Sleep   | 2188 |              | NULL
                                    |
|  20 | root | localhost:39223 | week1 | Query   |    0 | NULL         | SHOW PR
OCESSLIST                           |
| 104 | root | localhost:39526 | NULL  | Query   |  800 | Sending data | SELECT
1 FROM `week1`.`alarm` LIMIT 100000 |
| 105 | root | localhost:39527 | week1 | Query   |  800 | Sending data | SELECT
1 FROM `week1`.`alarm` LIMIT 100000 |
+-----+------+-----------------+-------+---------+------+--------------+--------
------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see if something have locked the table by issuing a [`SHOW PROCESSLIST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-processlist.html) command.