# insert values between rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, insert

I don't know if it can be done with just a sql query or it needs a php code
when a cid is **missing**

**There exist many missing values which I can't handle manually**

For example, here I don't have `cid=1` and `cid=6`.
I want to insert a row:

```
cid=1 tcp_sport='undefined' tcp_dport='undefined'
```

and

```
cid=6 tcp_sport='undefined' tcp_dport='undefined'
```

It seems to me I should create a procedure and insert between lines

another solution that I thaught was that I will create a table with cid and undifined values with the respective order and then join this one with that one and this join should have for example ifnull(tcp_sport,'')

would you please help me?

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't add this non-information to the database, but instead handle it in the code that uses this table.  E.g. when joining you can use LEFT, RIGHT or OUTER joins to deal with missing rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use PHP to automate this.

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

while($i < max_value_cid)//replace max_value_cid by the numeric maximum value of cid (SELECT MAX(cid) as max FROM table)
{
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE cid=".$i, $link);
   if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ($i, NULL, NULL);", $link);
   $i++;
}
?>
```

Do test the query on a sample set before execution and remember to backup the entire table, just-in-case.

Answer (score 4):

First, use MAX for get the largest ID.

`SELECT MAX(cid) as max FROM table`

Then, create a for loop for checking if the individual IDs exist:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    // $query = ... SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE cid = $i ...
    // check if the number of rows for $query is greater than 0
    // if not, INSERT INTO table VALUES ($i, DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The whole idea of an auto increment ID is to have a value that only refers to one thing ever. By "inserting between the lines" you may be opening yourself up to a lot of unforeseen problems. Image you have another table that has some values that link to the CID of this table. What if that table already has an entry for CID=1, When you insert a new item with CID=1 it will then join to that supporting record. So Data that really belongs to the original item with CID=1 will show for the new item which it probably has nothing to do with.

You aren't going to run out of ID values (if you are approaching the limit of integer, switch it to bigInt), don't re-use IDs if you can avoid it.

Comment: I can't avoid them I Have 46922 lines and I created a left join which is this one `create view alarm as select i.cid, i.ip_src, i.ip_dst, ifnull(t.tcp_sport,'') 
as tcp_sport, ifnull(t.tcp_dport, '') as tcp_dport
from ipview i,tcpview t where i.cid = t.cid;` then I had problem because php my admin will crash so I should only do this

Comment: That example isn't a left join... and shouldn't be causing any problems as written. phpMyAdmin is a tool, if it doesn't work, use another tool, don't make bad DB decisions because a tool is faulty.

Comment: yes I mixed up I meaned join but before that I tried left join too  this is my question which I didn't get proper answer but the state help me much more so I accepted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560159/why-creating-view-from-a-left-join-view-is-not-fast

Comment: I think maybe you're questions are too vague. There is obviously something you are trying to do here, and it's possibly flawed at the foundation and you're not seeing the effects of that flaw until you are up a few levels. If you keep building on this shaky foundation, more problems will become evident. You may need some consultation on your initial view creations to really get this done correctly.